# define_metric parameter ‘hidden’ not working?

Tags: wandb

I want specific metrics to be used exclusively as x-axis/independend variable in the Weights&Biases-Dashboard graphs. But no matter how I set them up, there are automatically generated panels in the Dashboard that plot these metrics against the step-count.

Here is my setup:

```
# define x-axes
wandb.define_metric("batch#", hidden=True)   # "hidden" not working
wandb.define_metric("epoch#", hidden=True)
# define metrics and match to x-axis
wandb.define_metric("loss", step_metric="#batch#")
wandb.define_metric("f1", step_metric="epoch#")
```

I want graphs of loss/batch# and f1/epoch# on my dashboard, but not graphs of batch#/step or epoch#/step. Therefore, I set the function parameter ‘hidden’ to True for these. It does not work, I still get automatically generated panels of them. Any advice?

Comment: hi, 
I work at W&B and was able to reproduce this. Someone from the support team will follow up here when there is a solution. In future, you can ask support questions in https://community.wandb.ai too FYI :) thanks